# $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ if $\langle f,f\rangle \in L^1(\Omega \times \Omega)$

Tags: analysis

if $f:\Omega \rightarrow H$ is a measurable function from a finite measure space to a separable Hilbert space, and if $$(w_1,w_2)\mapsto \langle f(w_1),f(w_2)\rangle$$ is in $L^1(\Omega \times \Omega, \mathbb{C})$, is $f$ in $L^1(\Omega ,H)$?

Comment: Certainly not necessarily if $H$ is infinite dimensional. Are you asking about a finite dimensional case?

Comment: @reuns In your example $\|f_t\|_{L^2}=t^{-1/2}$, so $f\in L^1([0,1],H)$ with respect to the standard Lebesgue measure. Do you mean some other power somewhere?

Comment: @fedja  thanks. no i had in mind a separable (i should have added this) infinite dimensional hilbert space.   apparently it's true if $\Omega$ is a compact real interval and $L^1$ is replaced with "Riemann integrable" (where one defines the riemann integral of f as a limit of riemann sums, as in the case when $f$ takes real values).  So i was hoping for a more general statement.  but maybe this is too much to hope for.  still its strange that it holds for the riemann but not lebesgue integral

Comment: Well, in the Riemann integral over a fixed compact interval, the difficulty is not in the $L^1$-norm bound (Riemann integrable functions are always bounded) but in the convergence of Riemann sums, so the generalization should go in some other direction.

Comment: @fedja yes good point.  so i wonder what happens if i add the hypothesis that $\langle f(x),f(y) \rangle$ is essentially bounded (ie in $L^\infty(\Omega x \Omega)$)

Comment: did the counter example you had in mind have unbounded <f,f>?

Comment: $f_t(x) = t^{-2}\cos(2\pi \lfloor e^{1/t} \rfloor x)\in L^2([0,1])$ then $\int_0^1 \langle f_t,f_u\rangle du \sim t^{-2} e^{-1/t} t^2$ and $\langle f_t,f_t\rangle^{1/2} = \frac14 t^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Following help from @fedja and @reuns, 
Let $v_1,v_2,...$ be orthonormal in H. Let $\Omega$ be an interval big enough to accomodate disjoint sets $A_n$, $n=1,2,3,..$ of measures $\lambda(A_n) = 1/n^2$ and define $f(x) = nv_n$ for $x\in A_n$.  Then $\int |f| = \sum_n 1/n = \infty$, yet $$\int \int|\langle f(x),f(y) \rangle |= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2\lambda(A_k)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2<\infty $$.